# libMagickCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, imagemagick, rmagick

I am facing is issue in my rails 3.2.17 application. I have install rmagick 2.13.2 ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 in my ubuntu machine. I did locate libMagick and I found the below list:

`$ locate libMagick
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.so.5.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.so.5.0.0`

Comment: Exeception: #<LoadError: libMagickCore.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545/extensions/x86_64-linux/1.9.1/rmagick-2.13.2/RMagick2.so>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RMagick2.so` is depends on `libMagickCore.so.4`, but you don't have it.

For workaround try this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.so.5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore.so.4
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.so.5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand.so.4
sudo ldconfig
```

If this does not work, probably, you need earlier version of ImageMagick.

Answer (score -4):

Finally I could find the solution. Hope this may help others also. Actually "libmagickcore4" libs was missing. So install it using below command.

`sudo apt-get install libmagickcore4`

Comment: November 2015: this gives: `E: Unable to locate package libmagickcore4`